# How to "export" a Map as a websites parameter on java EE

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have recently begun working with Tomcat and Java EE, and there is a function that can be used in .jsp files:

```
Map map = request.getParameterMap();
```

The **request.getParameterMap()** function takes a parameter such as this one

```
a=b&c=d&a=zzz&empty=&empty=&1=22
```

and puts it into a Map. Now I am wondering, is there a way to convert a Map that you already have to this sort of parameter to be appended on a url? Perhaps something like:

```
String parameter = map.getUrlParameter;
```

or do I have to write a function that does this manually?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in into Map<>. You'll have to write one.

Comment: Refer https://dzone.com/articles/two-ways-convert-java-map

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to add parameters to your URL? You can't/don't do this within the jsp file itself, you would have to take care of this in your controller when you generate the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Double> reader = new HashMap<>();


                String parameters = "?";
                Object[] array = reader.keySet().toArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.size(); i++) {
                    parameters = parameters + (array[i].toString()) + "=" + ((ArrayList) reader.get(array[i].toString()).keySet().toArray()[0]).toString() +
                            "&" + array[i].toString() + "=" + reader.get(array[i]).get(reader.get(array[i]).keySet().toArray()[0]).toString() + "&";
                }
```

Then this parameter string can be appended to a URL.